# Using `delete from TABLE where (......)` with multiple queries inside the brackets - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I currently have this query here:

```
select * from outerb where not exists(
Select * from wms
where wms.barcode = outerb.barcode)  
and (pcode = '' or pcode is null)
and (brand = '' or brand is null);
```

Query above gives me the following result:

- 2 tables been joined against the same column, in this case `barcode`. But have used `where not exists` so it shows me the values that do not exist between the two tables.
- also adding a another statement

`and (pcode = '' or pcode is null)
 and (brand = '' or brand is null);`

which shows me empty cells for specified cells.

Lastly, I need to delete all all these values from `outerb` based on the query above.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Delete from outerb where(
select * from outerb where not exists(
Select * from wms
where wms.barcode = outerb.barcode)  and (pcode = '' or pcode is null)
  and (brand = '' or brand is null));
```

but get an error message of `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the outer closure, just use an exists clause directly:

```
DELETE
FROM outerb t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wms t2
                  WHERE t2.barcode = t1.barcode AND
                        (t2.pcode = '' OR t2.pcode IS NULL) AND
                        (t2.brand = '' OR t2.brand IS NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

The In operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause same as multiple OR conditions.

```
DELETE FROM outerb AS ob
WHERE ob.ID_COLUMN IN (select ID_COLUMN from outerb where not exists(
Select * from wms
where wms.barcode = outerb.barcode)  and (pcode = '' or pcode is null)
  and (brand = '' or brand is null));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it